# SVGs and images are failing the unit testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I am writing unit tests for my React app and I came across an issue which is loading the SVGs in the React components that are tested as it always shows this error:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

I have set my `jest.config.js` to be as follows:

```
module.exports = {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/__test__/config/importJestDOM.ts'],
    collectCoverage: true,
    collectCoverageFrom: ['<rootDir>/src/**/*.{ts,tsx}'],
    coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['.d.ts'],
    testResultsProcessor: 'jest-sonar-reporter',
    moduleNameMapper: {
         '\\.(jpg|ico|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|og a)$':
      '<rootDir>/src/__test__/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
    '\\.(css|less|sass|scss)$': '<rootDir>/src/__test__/__mocks__/styleMock.js'
    },
    transform: {
      '\\.js$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest'
    }
};
```

And here is my styleMock.js & fileMock.js:

```
export default {}; // styleMock.js
```

```
export default ''; // fileMock.js
```

What is the problem here?